# WPF Recreation window in different STA thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher, sta

I need to create window with loading gif when my main window is rendering. I have read some articles and make a decision that for this purposes i need to create new thread. I did it like in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957969/how-do-i-open-a-window-on-a-new-thread)

As a result I have something like that:

```
LoadingDialog _loadingDlg;
Thread loadingThread;

public void ShowLoading()
{
    loadingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loadingThreadWork));
    loadingThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    loadingThread.Start();
}

private void loadingThreadWork()
{
    _loadingDlg = new LoadingDialog();
    _loadingDlg.Show();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}

public void HideLoading()
{
    _loadingDlg.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
}
```

First time when I call `ShowLoading()` and then `HideLoading()` everything works like I want. But when I call `ShowLoading()` at the second time I get an exception at

```
_loadingDlg.Show();
```

with message `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it`.

How can this be? `_loadingDlg` is created in the previous line, and in the same thread.

Comment: Why make a new window? Why not just make a grid that is centered, with visibility that you toggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `loadingThreadWork` you're creating the control, before the first run it's a `null`, so in first time you succeed. However, you're creating the dialog in a different thread, which is marked as an owner for the control.

At the next time you're calling the `loadingThreadWork`, control isn't null, and ant change for it from a different thread (and it is a different thread, because you're creating it again) leads to the exception you've got.

As you're using `WPF`, you probably should switch from threads to `async` operations, which are much more readable, supportable and predictable than your current solution.

Comment: Thanks. With you words I have found way to solve my problem. Is it right that the owner is determined for the class and not for instance? Can you give some article when I can read more detail about this.

Comment: No, owner is determined by instance. You can search by message error, this is a common error.

Comment: But with new thread I recreated an instance. And after this I get exception.